# loop through folders and sub folders using Jmeter requests

Tags: algorithm, jmeter

I have root folder and it's id. To get in to any folder I need to make POST request with Json in it's body that includes id of folder I want to get in to.As a response after POST request I'm getting list of folders inside. The question is next - how can I iterate through whole folder tree (visiting each folder) using WHILE Controller and POST request?

Comment: Please update your question with 2 JSON responses: 1. When there is a folder 2. When there are no folders (you hit the leaf folder) so we could come up with the relevant While Controller condition. In the meantime check out [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article.

Comment: @Dmitri except of folders I have files in folders. So when I have no folders in JSON response (I'm in leaf folder) I still have list of files. So my response is the same but in results Array I have no folder ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to achieve recursion with Jmeter. So I've used List to store lists of my SubFolders and when I've visited all items of SubFolder list I'm removing it from main List. This will work fine for not huge amount of folder tree levels. 
BeanShell was used to describe the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. First, add  [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler, to build POST request with parent folder id. (refer image1)
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child to above HTTP Sampler.(refer image2). Configure Regular Expression Extractor to capture all sub-folder ids from the HTTP Response. (refer imag2)
3. Add [For Each Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through all the sub-folder ids captured.(refer image3)
4. Add HTTP sampler as a child to For Each Controller. (refer image4)
5. Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) (to know variable values, captured using regex) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener (to capture HTTP request and response) to debug the script. Once script is working, remove them.

Following images are generated with an example on `google.com`. please change the values as per your web application.

Image1:
[image]

Image2:
[image]

Image3:
[image]

Image4:
[image]

Image5:
[image]

Comment: Ok, your solution is good only if folder tree has one level. Root folder and folders in the Root folder. But if we have more levels you wont be able to visit every sub folder of Root sub folders with solution you've provided.

Comment: It is recursion issue. difficult to simulate the problem at my end. can you share the URL?